# Synonyms for "taking cover"

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

What are synonyms for *taking cover*?

Is there a word that means "running to shelter or refuge to save myself from incoming pain or trouble"?

I want to use it in these contexts:

> Taking cover time.
>
> Time to take cover.

Comment: Any particular context or application? Is this for a warning 'take cover!' or a description 'he took cover'? For what kind of writing...a story, news, instructions?

Comment: 'Taking cover time' sounds weird (though logically OK). Its natural to want to parse it as 'taking (cover time)' and 'cover time' really isn't a thing. So 'Time to take cover' would be preferred.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about "taking refuge," "going into hiding" or "laying low."

Comment: "Refuge" is a good synonym for "cover" in OP's context, but I think either expression would normally imply evasive/protective action of relatively brief duration. Your other two suggestions both imply something done over a more extended period.

Answer (score 3):

You have actually mentioned a pretty useful word already -- `shelter`, which has the meaning you were looking for.

I think you probably might want to use its verb form.

> e.g. shelter sb/sth from sb/sth
>
> Sample sentence:
>
> We sat in the shade, sheltering from the sun.

Answer (score 1):

There is a phrase with the meaning you have asked for

"**Make oneself scarce**"

[Cambridge defines it as](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/make-yourself-scarce)

> make yourself scarce
>
> informal
>
> to go away from a difficult situation in order to avoid trouble
>
> Dad's really angry with you, so you'd better make yourself scarce.

As a single word, I would suggest **hide** or one of it's synonyms which mean taking cover.

However, I also see [**scram**](http://thesaurus.com/browse/scram) listed as a synonym of "make oneself scarce" which may apply in this case. [Scram](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/scram) means "leave abruptly" but when you say "Lets scram" it usually implies trouble is round the corner

> to leave a place very quickly, especially so that you do not get
>   caught

Comment: They don't really mean the same thing. To *make yourself scarce* means to *go elsewhere* (often, so you won't be found). To *take cover* means either to *hide* or (more often) *get behind some [nearby] protective barrier/screen*, but it invariably implies you'll remain in the vicinity.

Answer (score 0):

Try *entrench* or *barricade* with a reflexive pronoun—*barricade yourself time*. Reflexives don't always sound good in English, but they are used extensively in other languages, like Portuguese.

Why don't you drop the verb take. Call it *cover time* or *bunker time*.